# Save copy of worksheet and revoke all changes to the original

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that modifies the workbook it is executed in and I want that macro to save a copy of the workbook to a location (preferably specified by the user), revoke all changes to the workbook (so it's in its original state again) and close the workbook.

Unfortunately I can't find any input on the revoking and closing part... Saving a copy is pretty easy, but how to do the rest of those things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with most of brettdj's response (especially that you should save the file first). However, the BrowseForFolder function is unnecessary. Instead you can use the built-in Windows folder browser in post-2002 versions of Excel

```
Sub Example()

Dim strFolder as String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Save

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then 
    strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    'Quit/Show message asking to specify location
    End If
End With

'Do everything else

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFolder & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Close (False)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The (False) on closing the workbook is short for SaveChanges:=False, and may remove the need to switch off alerts

Also, if you wish to make the changes to a different workbook to the one containing the code, you may need [help using multiple Excel files](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/manipulating-multiple-files.php). The main lesson would be that you can substitute ActiveWorkbook for ThisWorkbook, or define the workbook upon opening

Comment: This works very nice so far... Is it possible to change the dialog so the user can name the file instead of just the location?

Comment: Yes...you can replace msoFileDialogFolderPicker with msoFileDialogSaveAs. Then "strFolder" will also include the file name, so you can simply use ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFolder. If you type "Application.FileDialog(" in VBA. you will get 4 different options displayed. You may be interested to look at them all (the others are "FilePicker" and "Open")

Answer (score 1):

Is the complex revoking necessary - why don't you just save the workbook as is at the start of the code (prior to mods), make the changes, saved the change file elswehere and close Excel?

**Update**
[Code sample that works on the workbook it is hosted in   caution it will save the the file and close it in that condtion ]

```
Sub SimpleSample()
Dim strFolder As String
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
'save current file in the location it was opened from
ThisWorkbook.Save

'make your mods here
'stuff

'get user directory
strFolder = BrowseForFolder
'save the modified workbook to the nuser selected folder (overwrite's any early version of the same name if they exist)
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFolder & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
'close the file
ThisWorkbook.Close
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
' Ken Puls, http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=284
'Function purpose:  To Browser for a user selected folder.
'If the "OpenAt" path is provided, open the browser at that directory
'NOTE:  If invalid, it will open at the Desktop level
Dim ShellApp As Object

'Create a file browser window at the default folder
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
               BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

'Set the folder to that selected.  (On error in case cancelled)
On Error Resume Next
BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
On Error GoTo 0

'Destroy the Shell Application
Set ShellApp = Nothing

'Check for invalid or non-entries and send to the Invalid error
'handler if found
'Valid selections can begin L: (where L is a letter) or
'\\ (as in \\servername\sharename.  All others are invalid
Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
Case Is = ":"
    If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
Case Is = "\"
    If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
Case Else
    GoTo Invalid
End Select

Exit Function

Invalid:

'If it was determined that the selection was invalid, set to False
 BrowseForFolder = False
  End Function
```

Comment: Posting here as I cant yet respond to Ed :). #1 Fair point on the DialogFolderPicker. #2 As soon as this line is executed, ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFolder & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, then the Workbook.Saved is True and the False argument on ThisWorkbook.Close is redundant. I used DisplayAlerts to suppress any potential file overwrite messages, it will of course also suppress any sheet deletes in the modified code process etc

Answer (score 0):

When you close a workbook, you have several options:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close False 
' closes the active workbook without saving any changes

ActiveWorkbook.Close True 
' closes the active workbook and saves any changes

ActiveWorkbook.Close 
' closes the active workbook and lets the user decide if 
' changes are to be saved or not
```

I guess the first one will suit you and fits to your case.